# Dosbox assembly loop instruction exists loop immediately

Tags: assembly, x86, tasm, dosbox

I had just started learning assembly and reading a book about it. In the book, all of the code is written and executed in dosbox. I had just read a chapter about the `loop` instruction and tried to create a very simple program that prints 'x' to the console a few times -

```
IDEAL
MODEL small
STACK 100h
DATASEG
; --------------------------
; Your variables here
; --------------------------

CODESEG
start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
; --------------------------
; Your code here
; --------------------------
    xor cx, cx
    mov cl, 10
    mov dl, 'x'

PrintX:
    mov ah, 2h
    int 21h
    loop PrintX

exit:
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h

END start
```

The problem is, when I step through the program, when I get to the `loop` instruction, then it sets `cx` to `0x0000` and exits the loop immediately. I can't really see what I'm doing wrong.

- The code is compiled using `TASM`

Comment: I didn't think `int 21h` would affect CX.  Are you sure your debugger is showing CX becoming `1` after the interrupt, right before execution reaches `loop PrintX`?  Because that's the only way for `loop` to not be taken.  It's the bottom of a `do{}while(--cx)` loop.

Comment: "The problem is, when I step through the program," What debugger and what step command are you using? It may be that the step you chose treated the `loop` as an instruction to proceed past.

Comment: http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah02 doesn't mention CX or DL being clobbered, so yeah, this code should be looping.  You could hoist the `mov ah, 2` outside the loop as well as the `dl` setting.   BTW, `mov cx, 10` (3 bytes, 1 instruction) would be a shorter more efficient way to set CX to 10, compared to two 2-byte instructions (xor and `mov cl,10`).

Comment: Does it actually print `'x'` 10 times or once?  If 10 times, your debugger isn't doing what you expect.  If once, that would be extremely weird, this is simple enough I don't think ecm and I could be missing something.  Her guess is what I was thinking, too; you might be using something like GDB's `until` command that single steps until reaching a later address than the current one, even if that means iterating through loops.

Comment: Ah, I see the problem. I'm using the `td` debugger and using the step function. I ran the code without the debugger and it did print out 10 x's. The problem was that I was stepping over the loop instead of tracing. Thanks @PeterCordes @ecm